# Keras Autoencoder Output jumps to zero

Tags: keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

*its my first question so I hope you forgive me for errors in the question.*

i want to learn lower represantations of input data with a simple autoencoder (keras).

unfortunately it seems as if the output jumps to zero in some places (look at the photo for details)

**Do you have any guesses why this could be?**

here is my code:

```
input_img = Input(shape=(300,))
encoder1 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(input_img)
decoder1 = Dense(300, activation='relu')(encoder1)

# this model maps an input to its reconstruction
autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoder1)

loss_metric = 'mae'
adam_opt = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False)


autoencoder.compile(optimizer=adam_opt, loss=loss_metric , metrics=[loss_metric])

callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor=loss_metric, patience=5)]

his = autoencoder.fit(X_train_res, X_train_res,
                epochs=500,
                batch_size=50000,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=(X_test_res, X_test_res),
                callbacks = callbacks)
```

[picture of reconstruction and original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXzMS.png)

Comment: Don't use relu in the output.

Comment: Maybe some more explanation: Relu sets negative outputs to 0. If certain pixel outputs are consistently negative, they are always set to 0 and the model doesn't get any gradients for these errors, so it is unable to "fix" them and they just stay at 0 after relu.